# "hdparm -s 1" on USB disk -> bricked? - USB drive is on power on in standby mode which cannot be reverted with hdparm

Tags: hard-drive, electrical-power, usb, hdparm

I have a disk which was apparently put into PUIS mode with hdparm.
As the disk does not spin up on power on automatically, I think I need to send it directly to the USB device (which is not even recognized as the device doesnt turn on)

I think this means the device is bricked but maybe someone has a solution?
The disk is a Western Digital My Passport 4TB with a WD Blue inside, model number WD40NMZW-11GX6S1 from 2018

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the disk out of his plastic box and plug in directly on a sata plug + power. you may have better results, or a least more diagnostics in the dmesg log.

Comment: unfortunately this model has no sata port, once out of the plastic disc, the usb is directly on the PCB, no adapter or anything like it
there are some log messages when i plug in the device that it cannot be accessed